# イーサネットの転送の仕組みについて

Tags: tcp

イーサネットⅡで1500バイト以上のデータを転送する場合、データを小分けにして繰り返し転送すると思うのですが、その場合データ転送だけではなく、宛先・送信元・タイプの指定も同じように繰り返されるのでしょうか？

それとも最初だけ宛先・送信元・タイプの指定をして、その後の通信はデータだけを転送する形になりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もちろん、分割されたフレームそれぞれにヘッダー情報が必要です。

Comment: やはり宛先・送信元・タイプも含めるのですね！
ありがとうございます！

Comment: 分割されたのはフレームではなく、パケットと思います。
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Data_Unit

Comment: @Jiu 質問文は[Ethernet IIのフレーム](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Ethernet_II)についてでは？ ちなみにタグにtcpが指定されていますが、質問文にはTCPもIPも触れられていません。

Comment: 間違えました。失礼いたしました。